# Dockerizing Node.js app

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

While trying to dockerize node app, when I visit localhost:8000 I get this error:

> The connection was reset - the connection to the server was reset
>   while the page was loading.

In the terminal when I use the run command on image, I get the desired output in console. It says:

> Server running at http://localhost:8000/

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node

RUN mkdir -p /app/
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app

RUN cd /app

RUN npm install

COPY . /app

CMD ["node", "index.js"]
EXPOSE 8000
```

index.js:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nodejs

var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8000, 'localhost');
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:8000/');
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "server1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Dockerizing node-app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Himanshu",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Here is the run command that I used

```
sudo docker run -p 8000:8000 -it --name node-container2 my-node-image
```

All these files are saved in same directory.

Comment: how do you run the container?

Comment: sudo docker run -p 8000:8000 -it --name node-container2 my-node-image

Comment: Add this to the question by editing it.

Comment: have you tried going to 0.0.0.0:8000 in your browser? Also, could you post the container logs please?

Comment: @Veve Okk I ll add it now

Comment: Yes I tried 0.0.0.0 It gives same result.
And this is the only thing I am getting on running the container

Server running at http://localhost:8000/
Were u asking for this?

Comment: the docker logs of the running container? like docker ps ...which will show you the running containers, copy the container id and run docker logs -f <container id> and that should display you some logs

Comment: Yeah I did that and got this..... Server running at http://localhost:8000/...
Nothing else

Answer (score 1):

Just change your `index.js` to work on `0.0.0.0` inside container:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nodejs

var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8000, '0.0.0.0');
console.log('Server running at http://0.0.0.0:8000/');
```

And you will be able to access your app via localhost on a host machine.

Comment: I have accepted but votes casted by those with less than 15 reputations are not displayed publicaly. Sorry :( and thank you for the help.